# paper trail gem - undefined local variable or method has_paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using the latest version of paper_trail gem (2.7.1) After the gem installed and table created I have added "has_paper_trail" in my model and end up with getting "**undefined local variable or method has_paper_trail**". I tried even with lower versions but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you restart your development server?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. This was my mistake. My server is running in the background and I completely forgot to restart it after the installation.

Comment: Great when there's such an easy fix. :-D

Comment: Thomas, I am getting up-votes for your suggestion. Better you post an answer, I will accept so that you will get the up-votes hereonwards.

Comment: No worries that's totally fine. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a silly mistake as we need to restart the server after gem installation.
Newbies like me often makes such mistakes. Full credit to Thomas for the kind information.